# Why "log in" logs in automatically?

Tags: discussion, login, auto-login

If I log out, click on 'log in', it automatically logs in before I have the chance to select a log in type. This doesn't sound right. It only works right when I choose the option to log out everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/

Comment: So if I am logged in in all the sites and another person uses my computer to log in to SO, he basically has to log me out from everywhere so he can log in?

Comment: @Tony That would be correct.

Comment: A disadvantage of the current login system but that's fine.